# how to categorize salary into high/med/low group in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have an employee dataset having salary details. I like to add an additional column to display their salary group like high/med/low:

**Data:**

```
Empno   Sal  Deptno
    1   800      20
    2  1600      30
    3  2975      20
    4  1250      30
    5  2850      30
    6  2450      10
    7  3000      20
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Empno     Sal    Deptno    Sal_Group
    1     800        20    low
    2    1600        30    mid
    3    2975        20    ...
    4    1250        30    ...
    5    2850        30    ...
    6    2450        10    ...
    7    3000        20    high
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
bins = np.linspace(min(df['Sal']), max(df['Sal']),4)
groupNames = ["low", "med", "high"]
df['SalGroup'] = pd.cut(df['Sal'], bins, labels = groupNames, include_lowest = True)
print(df)
```